# Ruby-Jmeter test case with existing cucumber test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, jmeter

I want to run Jmeter with my existing cucumber test cases, Off course Cucumber will not support stress testing, But instead of writing same test case for ruby-jmeter is there any way to run cucumber test case into jmeter.